# What's "to=3573072/3600000" means in the exception of java.io.EOFException: HttpConnectionOverHTTP?

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, jetty

One of my application gets the following exception from time to time when making HTTP calls. What's to=3573072/3600000? What may cause the error?

```
ERROR ProxyRequestTracker - event=RequestCompleted, closure=Error, errorType=proxyResponse, method=GET, agent=Geneos/GA5.6.0-210208 (Netprobe - WEB-MON), targetHost=d12d.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, targetPath=, actMs=3, jwtMs=3, totalMs=14
java.io.EOFException: HttpConnectionOverHTTP@666edd5::DecryptedEndPoint@6aca4ca{d12d.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/28.13.2.2:443/22.249.3.154:52302,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=3573072/3600000}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.earlyEOF(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.shutdown(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to=3573072/3600000
```

This is `timeout=<current>/<configured>`

So you have a timeout configured for 3,600,000 ms (1 hour).

The current timeout is at 3,573,072 ms.

So in about 26.9 seconds that connection will timeout if nothing happens on the connection (read or write).

The `java.io.EOFException` is telling you the connection was terminated, but you have to look at the logs around this connection line (before and possible after) to know more details on possible how/why the connection was closed.

Comment: Checked the log of the application and didn't find anything useful (just a log of it was going to make http GET to the url). Is the idel timeout too long?

Comment: The idle timeout could be set too long.  Have you updated your OS settings to allow an idle timeout of that length? (most OS's have default settings that are shorter then 1 hour)

Comment: How to check the idle timeout of the OS?

Comment: That's a different question, that I'm sure is answered in other places on the stackexchange websites.  Tip: make sure you narrow down your search to your specific OS version and distribution too.